# Is it advisable to encrypt url parameters instead of having them be in plain text?

Tags: php, url, encryption, parameters

I've had another developer pose the possibility of combining and encrypting/obsfucating all the parameters to pages for php, as a security measure against manipulations via crafted urls and to prevent interior knowledge of the database (e.g. knowing the id in the database of a specific entry).

In other words, instead of single or multiple public query parameters like ids, there would be a single encrypted blob that would be decrypted server-side, and re-encrypted when links are crafted.

Are there problems with this approach?  Are there substantial advantages that make it worthwhile?  Is this approach used in the wild to good effect?

Comment: The one potential drawback I could see is it makes testing a bit more difficult, since you can't just throw in whatever values you want, and instead have to recreate the encrypted blob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should design your system to prevent unauthorized access.  Obsfucating (useful encryption on data the client generates is not a possibility) is not a worthwhile defense.

For instead, instead of giving the user a database ID, given them a hash (with perhaps a session seed) of the ID.  The 128bit+ search space of the hash and (for reasonable DB sizes) low probability of collisions would be a much better approach.  You could also encrypt the ID on the server for values the client never needs to manipulate (with a seed) but make sure it has the same properties as the hash I mentioned—namely that the search space is very large compared to the possible value space.

Comment: I liked this answer better when it was just the first paragraph. :)

Comment: @sarnold: Me too, but I thought to toss a bone for potential solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent users from messing around with the GET arguments, i would recommend the following:

Add a hidden form to all of your pages. Clicking anywhere on the page, would fill-in some data into the form and submit it securely through POST / SSL. Along the submission details, pass the URL where you want to direct user to.

On the server side, collect arguments, put them into session either globally or under some sort of identifier which you append to the destination URL. Send redirect back. This way if user refreshes page, he's not nagged about POST data. Also if he starts messing with going back and sideways in the application, kill that session cache and send him to starting page.

I have seen this technique in some on-line banking softwares. Another benefit is that user can't open new window.

In my opinion it can add some degree of security, but would severely change development approach and give you more work. I never used this approach myself and I think that ID's are safe to pass around as long as you have a proper ORM system in place which under no circumstances won't let user A access data by user B regardless of what kind of code your developers will write.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some cases when this type of URL encryption (or Obsfucating) is useful. Let's say you build a pretty robust security in your application and all your hosts are safe and sound.

Now if your operations staff happens to be external and you don't want them to know/see these sensitive data (IDs) by changing log levels on the fly then it is better to encrypt them and decrypt them on demand by individual module.

As a general practice one should not pass any sensitive data in URL parameters and care should also be taken to NOT to log them even at higher level.